# Valid CSV filed import fails with Data between close double quote (") and field separator: field starts with

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to import a CSV file into BQ from GS.

The cmd I use is:

> $ bq load --field_delimiter=^ --quote='"' --allow_quoted_newlines
>   --allow_jagged_rows --ignore_unknown_values wr_dev.drupal_user_profile gs://fls_csv_files/user_profileA.csv
>   uid:string,first_name:string,last_name:string,category_id:string,logo_type:string,country_id:string,phone:string,phone_2:string,address:string,address_2:string,city:string,state:string,zip:string,company_name:string,created:string,updated:string,subscription:string

the reported error is

```
File: 0 / Line:1409 / Field:14, Data between close double quote (")
and field separator: field starts with: <Moreno L>
```

sample data is:

```
$ sed -n '1409,1409p' user_profileA.csv
$ 1893^"Moreno"^"Jackson"^17^0^1^"517-977-1133"^"517-303-3717"^""^""^""^""^""^"Moreno L Jackson \"THE MOTIVATOR!\" "^0^1282240785^1
```

which was generated from MySQL with:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/opt/mysql_exports/user_profileA.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '^' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM p;
```

Why I get the error message in BQ? How to properly export from MySQL CSV files that have newlines (`CR` and `LF` mixed, as it was user input from Windows or Mac)

Couple of job IDs:
Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:bqjob_r75d28c332a179207_0000014710c6969d_1
Job ID: aerobic-forge-504:bqjob_r732cb544f96e3d8d_0000014710f8ffe1_1

**Update**

Apparently it's more to this. I used `5.5.34-MariaDB-wsrep-log` INTO OUTFILE, and either is a bug or something wrong, but I get invalid CSV exports. I had to use other tool to export proper CSV. (tool: SQLYog)

it has problems with double quotes, for example Field 14 here has error:

```
3819^Ron ^Wolbert^6^0^1^6123103169^^^^^^^""Lil"" Ron's^0^1282689026^1
```

Comment: Try going thru Cloud SQL as an alternative: https://medium.com/google-cloud/loading-mysql-backup-files-into-bigquery-straight-from-cloud-sql-d40a98281229

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 2019:**

Try this as an alternative:

- Load the MySQL backup files into a Cloud SQL instance.
- Read the data in BigQuery straight out of MySQL.

Longer how-to:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/loading-mysql-backup-files-into-bigquery-straight-from-cloud-sql-d40a98281229

---

The proper way to encode a double quote in CSV is to put another double quote in front of it.

So instead of:

```
"Moreno L Jackson \"THE MOTIVATOR!\"...
```

Have:

```
"Moreno L Jackson ""THE MOTIVATOR!""...
```